# Will a native speaker notice if I say compare to instead of compare with?

Tags: prepositions

Will a native speaker notice if I say compare to instead of compare with and vice-versa?

For example, saying:

> 1 It's much easier compared to last time.

instead of:

> 2 It's much easier compared with last time.

I'm asking this because after doing some research I found out that according to:

"https://www.dailywritingtips.com/compared-to-or-compared-with/#:~:text=To%20compare%20to%20is%20to,essentially%20of%20the%20same%20order."

"To compare to is to point out or imply resemblances between objects regarded as essentially of a different order;

to compare with is mainly to point out differences between objects regarded as essentially of the same order."

Comment: Implicit in your question is that you believe one of them is better than the other. Can you edit to tell us what difference you see?

Comment: "Will a native speaker notice...?" type questions are surely opinion-based. For what it's worth, my UK experience is that careful speakers will notice, but many others won't.

Comment: A native speaker might notice you say "It's much easier **compared** to last time" instead of the more natural "It's much easier **than** last time" before thinking about the 'to/with' aspect.

Comment: I think the distinction made by that blog is not widely observed in general use by fluent speakers. Many peopel treat "compared to" and "compared with" as interchangeable.